# How does one return a local CComSafeArray to a LPSAFEARRAY output parameter?

Tags: c++, com, atl, safearray

I have a COM function that should return a SafeArray via a `LPSAFEARRAY*` out parameter.
The function creates the SafeArray using ATL's `CComSafeArray` template class.
My naive implementation uses `CComSafeArray<T>::Detach()` in order to move ownership from the local variable to the output parameter:

```
void foo(LPSAFEARRAY* psa)
{
    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> ret;
    ret.Add(CComVariant(42));
    *psa = ret.Detach();
}

int main()
{
    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> sa;
    foo(sa.GetSafeArrayPtr());

    std::cout << sa[0].lVal << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that `CComSafeArray::Detach()` performs an `Unlock` operation so that when the new owner of the SafeArray (main's `sa` in this case) is destroyed the lock isn't zero and `Destroy` fails to unlock the SafeArray with `E_UNEXPECTED` (this leads to a memory leak since the SafeArray isn't deallocated).

What is the correct way to transfer ownership between to CComSafeArrays through a COM method boundary?

---

**Edit:** From the single answer so far it seems that the error is on the client side (`main`) and not from the server side (`foo`), but I find it hard to believe that `CComSafeArray` wasn't designed for this trivial use-case, there must be an elegant way to get a SafeArray out of a COM method into a `CComSafeArray`.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: This happens for both VS8 (2005) and VS9 (2008)

Comment: Based on my experience I believe whoever designed CComSafeArray never actually used it. You can use your own wrapper class if you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you set the receiving `CComSafeArray`'s internal pointer directly.
Use the `Attach()` method to attach an existing `SAFEARRAY` to a `CComSafeArray`:

```
LPSAFEARRAY ar;
foo(&ar);
CComSafeArray<VARIANT> sa;
sa.Attach(ar);
```

Comment: Surely this isn't the way `CComSafeArray` is supposed to be used, it goes against the grain of `CComVariant` and `CComBSTR`.

Comment: As you saw in the code, the CComSafeArray expects the SAFEARRAY to be locked. You have to lock it some way or the other.

Comment: And there is no Attach-like functionality that locks and also no Detach-like function that doesn't Unlock - so the work has to be done on either the callers or the callees side.

Answer (score 5):

Just to confirm that the marked answer is the correct one.  RAII wrappers cannot work across COM boundaries.

The posted method implementation is not correct, you cannot assume that the caller is going to supply a valid SAFEARRAY.  Just [out] is not a valid attribute in Automation, it must be either [out,retval] or [in,out].  If it is [out,retval], which is what it looks like, then the method must create a new array from scratch.  If it is [in,out] then the method must destroy the passed-in array if it doesn't match the expected array type and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that where was no intent to allow such a use case. Probably it was not the same developer who wrote `CComVariant` & `CComPtr` :)

I believe that `CComSafeArray`'s author considered value semantics as major goal; Attach/Detach might simply be a "bonus" feature.

Comment: And even with this reasonong, I still feel like `CComSafeArray`'s default ctor and `GetSafeArrayPtr` are design flaws/workarounds...