# Is this CComSafeArray usage bad?

Tags: c++, com, safearray

I have a COM function:

```
GetData(SAFEARRAY ** pRetVal)
```

and following legacy code:

```
CComSafeArray<double> saDataArray;
hr = pmyInterface->GetData(&saDataArray.m_psa);
SafeArrayLock(saDataArray);
```

I doubt if that is good to manually manage locks. Will that code crash when `m_psa` was returned as `NULL` by `GetData`?

How about following code? Is that better?

```
LPSAFEARRAY psa;
CComSafeArray<double> saDataArray;
hr = pmyInterface->GetData(&psa);
saDataArray.Attach(psa);
```

**EDIT:**
I tested both of the code above. There is one difference. If `GetData` returns `NULL`, directly `Attach` it without `NULL` check will invoke a exception. And the first version will return a `E_INVALIDARG`. My question still remains, do you prefer the later version since it use SafeArray object to maintain the counting, rather than mixing it?

**EDIT2:**
If for whatever reason I choose the first version, is that okay to ignore the `E_INVALIDARG` return value? Will that have any side effect when some code later use this `saDataArray`?

Comment: There is no `SafeArray` type in the ATL libs, or anywhere else in MS tools. You may have meant `LPSAFEARRAY`. Also, ATL::CComSafeArray provides a method to get the address of the internal pointer for out-val usage. [CComSafeArray::GetSafeArrayPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s10dhw5(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I don't know if it might be a possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778491/how-does-one-return-a-local-ccomsafearray-to-a-lpsafearray-output-parameter)...

Comment: I've edited your question just to better format code inside question text.

Comment: You'd be interested in handling `hr` errors as soon as they appear. If you skip the first one, you are likely to get `E_INVALIDARG` on the next API call to `SafeArrayLock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> ```
> SafeArray * psa;
> CComSafeArray<double> saDataArray;
> hr = pmyInterface->GetData(&psa);
> saDataArray.Attach(psa);
> ```

But I think the actual code should be:

```
LPSAFEARRAY psa; // not "SafeArray *"
hr = pmyInterface->GetData(&psa);
CComSafeArray<double> saDataArray;
saDataArray.Attach(psa);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778491/how-does-one-return-a-local-ccomsafearray-to-a-lpsafearray-output-parameter) for further details.

**EDIT: Updating answer based on your question edits.**

I really don't like your first code:

> ```
> CComSafeArray<double> saDataArray;
> hr = pmyInterface->GetData(&saDataArray.m_psa);
> SafeArrayLock(saDataArray); // <--- Explicit lock on a CComSafeArray-wrapped array
> ```

In fact, once the raw `SAFEARRAY` is given to a C++ RAII wrapper (`CComSafeArray`), from that point in time on I would only use this wrapper and its methods to manipulate the array.
If you want to do "manual" handling of the array, just `.Detach()` it from the C++ wrapper, and use Win32 API function calls. But mixing both is not good quality code, IMO.

Note that the second approach is different, since you first use the raw `SAFEARRAY`, make the `GetData()` method fill it, and then you `.Attach()` it to the `CComSafeArray` C++ RAII wrapper, *transferring ownership* ("*move semantics*") to that wrapper. Then it's OK to use the wrapper methods to manipulate the array.

In addition, in production quality code, I would not ignore error `HRESULT`s.

Comment: That's right, it is LPSAFEARRAY. Seems majority prefer using CComSafeArray to handle the lock. But my question remains, is it okay to ignore the E_INVALIDARG?

Comment: No, if you get E_INVALIDARG, from Attach(), that's because the author of that function considers it part of its contract that its input parameter be non-null. So you should guard your call to attach with a null pointer check rather than calling and ignoring the result.This will be safer (as you won't be ignoring catch other potential error codes), and more readable anwyay.